# Eureka not working with Swift 5 | Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, podfile, eureka-forms

I've got to gather three different sections of data from users. Instead of building all the forms myself and it taking forever, I decided to use a third party pod. I found that Eureka is largely used. For some reason, it WILL NOT work for me, no matter what tutorial I follow.

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Pics2Report' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Pics2Report
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  target 'Pics2ReportTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Pics2ReportUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

pod 'SCLAlertView'
pod 'HGPlaceholders'
pod 'FloatingPanel'
pod 'BEMCheckBox'
pod 'Eureka'

end
```

It says I installed the pod successfully. Inside my project, I try to run this code:

```
import Foundation
import Eureka
import UIKit

class FileDetailsViewController: FormViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            form +++ Section("About You")
                <<< TextRow() { row in
                    row.title = "Name"
                    row.placeholder = "Your Name"
                }
        }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        //Lock screen into portrait mode
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }
    
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Missing arguments for parameters 'options', 'isOpened' in call
```

for this line of code:

```
form +++ Section("About You")
```

and this error:

```
Binary operator '<<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Section' and 'TextRow'
```

for this line of code:

```
<<< TextRow() { row in
```

What am I doing wrong here?? Is Eureka outdated? It's like it's not recognizing that it's proper Eureka formatting. Is there a better form builder that will allow me to use expandable/collapsable sections with textfields and a date picker inside?

Comment: Do you really mean iOS 4, where at iOS 15 now?

Comment: I tried this on my machine and it worked fine, so surely your problem has something to do with your mention of "iOS 4." This must be a typo considering that iOS 4 is long unsupported by Apple. Do you mean iOS 14? Swift 4? Something else?

Comment: It was a typo. I'm using Swift 5, according to the Build Settings. Did I enter something wrong with my Podfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka Swift 5 fix: Add **Eureka.** before Section

```
form
    +++ Eureka.Section("mysection")
        <<< TextRow("myrow") {
            $0.title = "Title"
            $0.placeholder = "Placeholder"
            $0.value = "myvalue"
            $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
        }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
            if !row.isValid {
                cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .systemRed
            }
        }
```